# Python dictionary replace values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 20 000 plus entries with at the moment simply the unique word and the number of times the word was used in the source text (Dante's Divine Comedy in Italian).

I would like to work through all entries replacing the value with an actual definition as I find them. Is there a simple way to iterate through the keywords that have as a value a number in order to replace (as I research the meaning)?

The dictionary starts:

```
{'corse': 378, 'cielo,': 209, 'mute;': 16, 'torre,': 11, 'corsa': 53, 'assessin': 21, 'corso': 417, 'Tolomea': 21}  # etc.
```

Sort of an application that will suggest a keyword to research and define.

Comment: I ended up packing a fresh dictionary. It works, but it's really inefficient. `dict` feels like a mess.

Answer (score 133):

#### via dict.update() function

In case you need a *declarative* solution, you can use [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to change values in a dict.

Either like this:

```py
my_dict.update({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
```

or like this:

```py
my_dict.update(key1='value1', key2='value2')
```

#### via dictionary unpacking

Since **Python 3.5** you can also use *dictionary unpacking* for this:

```
my_dict = { **my_dict, 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Note: This creates a new dictionary.

#### via merge operator or update operator

Since **Python 3.9** you can also use the *merge operator* on dictionaries:

```
my_dict = my_dict | {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Note: This creates a new dictionary.

Or you can use the *update operator*:

```
my_dict |= {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: the `key1` in `key1='value1'` is not a variable. Even if your `key1` is a variable, it interprets as a string `'key1'`.

Answer (score 93):

You cannot select on specific values (or types of values). You'd either make a reverse index (map numbers back to (lists of) keys) or you have to loop through *all* values every time.

If you are processing numbers in arbitrary order anyway, you may as well loop through all items:

```
for key, value in inputdict.items():
    # do something with value
    inputdict[key] = newvalue
```

otherwise I'd go with the reverse index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

reverse = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in inputdict.items():
    reverse[value].append(key)
```

Now you can look up keys by value:

```
for key in reverse[value]:
    inputdict[key] = newvalue
```

Comment: In Python 2, if iterating over a large dictionary, use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` so that the entire dictionary contents aren't loaded into memory. (This doesn't matter for Python 3 since `items()` basically does what `iteritems()` did in Python 2.)

Comment: @nofinator: in Python 2, you use `iteritems()` to prevent the creation of a new list list with len(dictionary) tuples referencing the key-value pairs in the dictionary (rather a waste when only iterating). The dictionary contents themselves are *always* loaded into memory. Not that this applies here, as the question is tagged Python 3 :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters can we have the same setting to retrieve the old value somehow? Like if `.update()` returned the old value, it would have saved me a step of saving the old value and then replacing in case I want to do that

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan: not sure what you are asking; the question here was about finding a key for a given value, and then using that key to replace something *somewhere else*. I think you are asking if you can get the old value for a given key, and at the same time put in the new value? There is not, just use two statements: `old = d.get(key)` in case a missing key is not an error, or use `old = d[key]` otherwise, and then use `d[key] = new`.

Answer (score 10):

If you iterate over a dictionary you get the keys, so assuming your dictionary is in a variable called `data` and you have some function `find_definition()` which gets the definition, you can do something like the following:

```
for word in data:
    data[word] = find_definition(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you solve your issue.

Imagine you have a dictionary like this:

```
dic0 = {0:"CL1", 1:"CL2", 2:"CL3"}
```

And you want to change values by this one:

```
dic0to1 = {"CL1":"Unknown1", "CL2":"Unknown2", "CL3":"Unknown3"}
```

You can use code bellow to change values of `dic0` properly respected to `dic0to1` without worrying yourself about indexes in dictionary:

```
for x, y in dic0.items():
    dic0[x] = dic0to1[y]
```

Now you have:

```
>>> dic0
{0: 'Unknown1', 1: 'Unknown2', 2: 'Unknown3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do something similar. My approach for sanitizing data for python based on Sadra Sabouri's answer:

```
def sanitize(value):
    if str(value) == 'false':
        return False
    elif str(value) == 'true':
        return True
    elif str(value) == 'null':
        return None
    return value

for k,v in some_dict.items():
        some_dict[k] = sanitize(v)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
data = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}

for key in data:
   if key == key1:
       data[key1] = change
       print(data)
```

this will replace key1: value1 to key1: change