# remove text between two characters without changing datatype

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that contains some html. Removing characters between `<` and `>` seems to work for what I want to do. However, I am using `clean_data = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', str(data))` which converts my list of dicts to a string. I need to retain the list of dicts structure so that I can do some follow-on work that requires filtering the list of dicts using indexes, keys, etc.

How can I remove all characters between (and including) `<` and `>` while retaining my existing data structure of list of dicts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773669/python-dictionary-replace-values)

Answer (score 3):

TRY:

```
import re
d={'a':'a<11>gg','b':'dq<ss>ss'}
print({k:re.sub(r'<.*?>','',v) for k,v in d.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'agg', 'b': 'dqss'}
```

For list of dicts do:

```
import re
lod=[{'a':'a<11>gg','b':'dq<ss>ss'},{'1':'12<aa>11','2':'aa<11>11'}]
print([{k:re.sub(r'<.*?>','',v) for k,v in d.items()} for d in lod])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution is to recursively traverse the given data structure and react to different data types differently so that it would work for any nested data structures consisting of dicts and/or lists of strings:

```
import re
def recursive_replace(data, regex, repl, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            data[k] = recursive_replace(v, regex, repl, *args, **kwargs)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(data):
            data[i] = recursive_replace(v, regex, repl, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        data = re.sub(regex, repl, data, *args, **kwargs)
    return data
```

so that:

```
print(recursive_replace([{'a':'a<11>gg','b':'dq<ss>ss'},{'1':'12<aa>11','2':'aa<11>11'}], r'<.*?>', ''))
print(recursive_replace({'a':['a<11>gg','dq<ss>ss'],'b':['12<aa>11','aa<11>11']}, r'<.*?>', ''))
would output:

[{'a': 'agg', 'b': 'dqss'}, {'1': '1211', '2': 'aa11'}]
{'a': ['agg', 'dqss'], 'b': ['1211', 'aa11']}
```