# Convert "\u0000" in False and "\u0001" in True in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm print a dictionary like JSON in Python2, I'm using `print(json.dumps(request_dr.data['data']))` but right now the output from my console is:

```
{
   "id": 711,
   "username": "esteban@gtt",
   "first_name": "esteban@gtt",
   "last_name": "",

    ... Anothers fields

   "passwordChangedOnce": "\u0001",
   "ldapCheck": "\u0000"
 }
```

So, How Can I convert passwordChangedOnce to true and ldapCheck to false, in order to I get some like this:

```
{
   "id": 711,
   "username": "esteban@gtt",
   "first_name": "esteban@gtt",
   "last_name": "",

    ... Anothers fields

   "passwordChangedOnce": "true",
   "ldapCheck": "false"
 }
```

I have read another answers in Stack Overflow but I haven't had success. Thanks

Comment: "I'm print a dictionary like JSON in Python2" -- Two things: Firstly, extract a [mcve] and show the code. Secondly, why do you write such code yourself, why not just use a JSON codec library?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm using **json** module, this module is by default in Python2

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].** _this module is by default in Python2_ What do you mean? Is there any particular reason you're using Python 2?

Comment: If the JSON decoding is already done, you don't have JSON, you just have a normal Python dictionary. So this isn't a question about JSON decoding, it's "how do I search for key/value pairs in my dictionary where the value is '\u0001' and change it to true?"; why does this talk about JSON at all?

Comment: This smells a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19773721/14122

Comment: "I'm using json module, this module is by default in Python2" - this is not true. `json` is a standard library that comes with every version of Python, including any version of Python 3. Please use a modern version of Python, everyone else is.

Comment: However, regardless of the Python version, it looks like the data you're getting from the request is simply encoding `True` as a character `\u0001` and `False` as a character `\u0000` - either you convert all dictionary values like that to booleans, or you need to be able to specify which fields to convert and explicitly convert them.

Comment: wait, `"true"` and `"false"`, not `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing fancy or automatic about this -- if you want to do a search-and-replace on values, *write code that does a search-and-replace on values*.

```
def convertDict(d):
    for (k, v) in d.items():
        if v == '\x00':   # this is the same string that json serializes as "\u0000"
            d[k] = False
        elif v == '\x01': # this is the same string that json serializes as "\u0001"
            d[k] = True
    return d

print(json.dumps(convertDict(request_dr.data['data'])))
```