# Pass same keyword argument to a function twice

Tags: python, python-3.8

This is two questions, and I'd be happy with either being answered (unless one method is preferred to another).

I have a function, say

```
def my_func(a, b, c, d = None):
    print(a)
    print(f"I like {b}")
    print(f"I am {c}")
    if d:
        print(d)
```

I have a dictionary of keywords my_dict = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Dogs', 'c': 'Happy', 'd': 10} which are always passed as inputs to the function my_func(**kwargs).

My questions are:

1. If I want to input a different value, say a='Goodbye', is there a way I can input the same argument twice overriding the first entry with the second instance of it?
2. Alternatively, is there something comparable to my_dict.update({'a': 'Hello'}) that won't change the values in the dictionary permanently, but will let me pass in a different value for a specific keyword?

I know I can create a new dictionary and pass that in, but I think it would be cleaner if I could do it without needing to do this (though feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!).

Edit: I'm using Python 3.8.

Comment: [Python dictionary replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19773669/6045800)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 3.5 and up, you can unpack `my_dict` into a new dict and override the `'a'` entry:

```
my_func(**{**my_dict, 'a': 'Goodbye'})
```

On Python 3.9 and up, you can use the `|` operator to create a new dict by merging entries from two dicts. Values for duplicated keys will be taken from the second dict:

```
my_func(**my_dict | {'a': 'Goodbye'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.3, you can use [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

> A ChainMap groups multiple dicts or other mappings together to create
> a single, updateable view.[...]
>
> Lookups search the underlying mappings successively until a key is
> found. [...]
> A ChainMap incorporates the underlying mappings by reference. So, if
> one of the underlying mappings gets updated, those changes will be
> reflected in ChainMap.

So, your code could be:

```
from collections import ChainMap

def my_func(a, b, c):
    print(a)
    print(f"I like {b}")
    print(f"I am {c}")
    
my_dict = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Dogs', 'c': 'Happy'} 
new = {'a':'Goodbye' }

my_func(**ChainMap(new, my_dict))
#Goodbye
#I like Dogs
#I am Happy
```

Note that `new` must come *before* `my_dict`, as the value will be taken from the first dict that contains the key.

Since Python 3.10, you can use the `|` operator:

> d | other
>
> Create a new dictionary with the merged keys and values of d
> and other, which must both be dictionaries. The values of other take
> priority when d and other share keys.

So, you could call your function with

```
my_func(**(my_dict | new))
```

Note that in this case, `new` must come *after* `mydict.